# GAE + Python + Sendmail + Form = mail not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendmail

I am not able to receive any mail in my google application.

The relevant codes are:

**main.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

# Sets the "inicio.html" website as the default page
class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        path='inicio.html'
        if self.request.url.endswith('/'):
            path = '%sinicio.html'%self.request.url

        self.redirect(path)

    def post(self):have the following 
        self.get()

# Sends an email with the fields of the form
class OnSendFormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
      cf_name=self.request.get('cf_name')
      cf_email=self.request.get('cf_email')
      cf_subject=self.request.get('cf_subject')
      cf_body=self.request.get('cf_message')

      message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="GAE Account <validAccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com>",
                                  to = "personalAccount <existentAccount@gmail.com>",
                                  subject = cf_subject,
                                  body = cf_body)
      message.send()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexHandler),
                                      ('/on_send_form', OnSendFormHandler)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that there is a handler for the form '/on_send_form'.

The relevant html form:

```
       <form action="/on_send_form" method="post" id="contacts-form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="grid3 first">
            <label title="Escriba su nombre y apellidos">Nombre:<br />
              <input type="text" name="cf_name" value=""/>
            </label>
            <label title="Escriba la dirección de correo electrónico donde quiere que le enviemos la respuesta a su consulta">E-mail:<br />
              <input type="email" name="cf_email" value=""/>
            </label>
            <label title="Escriba la razón principal de su mensaje">Asunto:<br />
              <input type="text" name="cf_subject" value="" title="Escriba la razón principal de su mensaje"/>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="grid5">Mensaje:<br />
            <textarea name="cf_message" title="Escriba su consulta con detalle. Le responderemos a la dirección de correo electrónico indicada en un plazo máximo de 24 horas"></textarea>
            <div class="alignright">
              <a href="#" class="alt" onClick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').reset()">Limpiar Campos</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="alt" onClick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit()">Enviar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Both the form and the handler uses the POST method. I deploy the GAE application with the option.
    --enable_sendmail

The logs in GAE say that the everything was ok.

I read the documentation and I don't know that I am missing.

Thank you in advance,
DConversor

Comment: you cant deploy an app with `--enable_sendmail`. thats a SDK flag for dev_appserver.py. what are you actually doing? local or really deployed?

Comment: Really deployed on GAE. Where I am supossed to add the flag then ? Do I need to specify that I want to use mail, somewhere in the google application dashboard?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special; the mail API is always enabled on production. You don't have to explicitly turn it on in the dev server because it's intended for testing, and 95% of the time you don't want to actually send the messages.

Comment: don't think so. as far as i know its enabled by default. do you get any error messages? if not try to log it yourself with the logging module.

Comment: try one thing. change `to = "personalAccount <existentAccount@gmail.com>"` --> `to = "existentAccount@gmail.com"` and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Your handlers in your `WSGIApplication` constructor are in the wrong order; they're checked in the order they're given, and `'/.*'` matches all URLS, so the `'/on_send_form'` on is never checked. Put the catchall expression last.

Comment: This seems to be the cause of the problem. I changed the order and it seems to work, except for the following problem that I found now:           File "....main.py", line 32, in post
    message.send()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 900, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender

Comment: Okey, it works!!   I wasn't using my email address.  The only problem I have now, given the main.py above, is that after sending the mail (pressing the submitting button), I see a white page, whithout content. The URL says '...appspot.com/on_send_form'. How can I return to the page containing the form?      Thank you guys.

Comment: @Dconversor: add `self.redirect('/')` to the end of the handler?

Comment: Thank you very much. Every thing is perfect now. I also did some minor changes. I will post a link to the running example for others with similar problems. Thanks again Woobie and thanks all the other people for the support. DConversor

Comment: I reopen the question, is it possible to show a confirmation message after sending the mail and redirecting? I would like to show just a pop up. I had a php version of the form that showed a confirmation pop up, but now with python I don't know how to display just a pop up and no a whole new page. Thank you

Comment: Fixed with the following:                                                                                                               self.response.out.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\" Message  \");window.location='/';</script>")